# jQuery not finding element after react render

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and I have the following:

main.js

```
handleClick: function(e) {
  //other code
  var myComponent = <MyComponent data={options} />;
  React.render(myComponent, document.getElementById("modal_inner"));
  modal_popup(options);
}
render: function() {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.handleClick}>some text</div>
  );
}
```

myComponent.js

```
// other code
var insert = [];
render: function() {
  if(this.props.data.label == "one") {
    insert.push(<div id="datepicker">text</div>);
  }
  else {
    insert.push(<div id="otherElem">text</div>);
  }

  return (
    {insert}
  );
}
```

modal.js

```
function modal_popup(options, callbackFnc) {
  //some code
  console.log($('#datepicker').html());
}
```

Description of what happens: 
When I load the main.js page in a browser, there are several buttons with the onClick event. If button "one" is clicked, then in myComponent.js, the datepicker DIV is added to the modal.

The problem is:
When I click on button "one," it works fine. When I click on another button, THEN go back to button "one," the modal.js is not finding the datepicker element (i.e. it's coming back as "undefined" when I try to find the element itself or the html() inside it). When I view source, the datepicker element is there.

I did console.log in each step/lifecycle in React and it appears to render the correct element. So I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Aren't you pushing another div#datepicker into your html, the second time you click on "one"? Multiple div's with the same id could cause this problem.